# R data.table: How can I merge a list of data.tables?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a long list of data.tables. I want to merge (inner join) them all in a single data.table.

With `dplyr` and `purrr` I can do:

```
dt1 <- data.table(cbind(letters[1:10], 1:10))
dt2 <- data.table(cbind(letters[3:12], 3:12))
dt3 <- data.table(cbind(letters[5:15], 5:15))

dtl <- list(dt1, dt2, dt3)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
merged <- dtl %>% reduce(inner_join, by='V1')
```

How can I do this with data.table?

Comment: FYI, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4370) with proposals for `mergelist` and related functions. The current approach is to use `Reduce(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use join `on`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(Reduce(function(x, y) x[y, on = .(V1)], dtl))
```

Comment: Thank you. From what I can test the data.table solution is not significantly faster than my current dplyr + purrr, which is a million times nicer to read...

Comment: @francoiskroll okay, thank you for the comment. I thought the question was about how to do this in data.table

Comment: Oh yeah it totally was sorry! I guess I'm just disappointed there isn't a big difference as with everything data.table :)

Comment: @francoiskroll its okay.  In most cases, data.table is efficient.  I was not aware that there would be a bigger difference in this case